# Twitter-Bootstrap: Content is overlapping sticky-footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

My content is overlapping my footer (which is sticky). But it should have a normal padding-top. How  I use CakePHP (not relevant) and Twitter Bootstrap.
On some pages it works, and on other not. How can I fix this?

**CSS**

```css
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
footer {
    padding: 17px 0 18px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -63px;
}
.push {
    height: 63px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid wrapper">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span11">
            //content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">          
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span8">
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="footer-links pull-right>
                  //content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-floor">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                //content
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the sticky footer to work, you have to set heights for both `.push` and `.footer`. Try adding the `63px` height to your footer as well.

```
.push, footer {
height: 63px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your footer somehow z-index over sidebar z-index.